# I can't make a href works on my caroussel

Tags: html, css

i needed to use a caroussel for my website but i also need that every pictures in the caroussel must be clickabe (or at least a link in the picture must be clickable).

I tryied to create a button, put the a href around the div. I don't see where there is something wrong but it doesn't work

thank you in advance for your answer

Ps:I just started to develop, so i may done something stupid

```css
body {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 500px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 30px 30px 30px 30px 30px 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

main#carousel {
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  perspective: 600px;
  --items: 5;
  --middle: 3;
  --position: 1;
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: coral;
  --r: calc(var(--position) - var(--offset));
  --abs: max(calc(var(--r) * -1), var(--r));
  transition: all 0.25s linear;
  transform: rotateY(calc(-10deg * var(--r))) translateX(calc(-300px * var(--r)));
  z-index: calc((var(--position) - var(--abs)));
}

div.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  --offset: 1;
  background-color: #90f1ef;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(2) {
  --offset: 2;
  background-color: #ff70a6;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(3) {
  --offset: 3;
  background-color: #ff9770;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(4) {
  --offset: 4;
  background-color: #ffd670;
}

div.item:nth-of-type(5) {
  --offset: 5;
  background-color: #e9ff70;
}

input:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(1):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 1;
}

input:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 3 / 4;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(2):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 2;
}

input:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column: 4 /5;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(3):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column: 5 / 6;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(4):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 4;
}

input:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column: 6 / 7;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
}

input:nth-of-type(5):checked~main#carousel {
  --position: 5;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="radio" name="position" checked />
  <input type="radio" name="position" />
  <input type="radio" name="position" />
  <input type="radio" name="position" />
  <input type="radio" name="position" />
  <main id="carousel">
    <div class="item"><a href='google.com'>test</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href='google.com'>test</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href='google.com'>test</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href='google.com'>test</a></div>
    <div class="item"><a href='google.com'>test</a></div>
    <main>
</body>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/bpichery/pen/oNZYGgd  Project's Link

Comment: Read [ask] and [mcve], then add your code into the question please

Comment: You have `pointer-events: none;` so what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on main#carousel in your css
removing this should solve the problem

It prevents any click and hover events on an element